# How to I access this web service?

Tags: javascript, web-services

I am used to working with services where I'd use the IDE to create a proxy that points to the address provided to me and gets all pertinent info. However, in this case, a 3rd party has created a service in a format I am unfamiliar with. It seems to be a Javascript service.  They told me this was the address...however it generates an error

Endpoint: http://www.medicaideligibilityapi.org/determinations/eval

Then they told me I had to hit this function:

https://github.com/HHSIDEAlab/medicaid_eligibility/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/services.js#L549

If anybody can just give me a push in the right direction I'd appreciate it. They are not quick to respond and I need to get this done.

Comment: It looks like you need to post the right data to it and then you'll get a reply in JSON. It may be easier to take the angular application from github and get it running (if that's easy enough) then use your browser's debugger to watch traffic to that web service. Alternatively you should be able to figure out the input and output data from that .js class: it looks like the input is JSON constructed from Application.prototype.serialize().

Comment: Did you hit the first URL with `POST`?

Comment: Hate to sound like a newbie, but I've been trying to figure out HOW to hit the first URL. Not sure what it is.

Comment: What language are you working with? JavaScript too, or something else? It should have a web framework that supports POST requests (i.e. form submission in browser terms, although you'll be posting JSON data probably and not a form)

Comment: After some research, this appears to be Ruby on Rails. The javascript file above has the very basic service I need to hit, but can't figure out how to hit it.